# Swap two composables

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to swap two composables by preserving their states? Let's say I've two TextFields positioned vertically. When a button clicked TextFields should swap their places (one should go down and the other up).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy if you don't need animation:

```
val state by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

Column {
    if (state) {
        TextField1(...)
        TextField2(...)
    } else {
        TextField2(...)
        TextField1(...)
    }

// Somewhere in Button's onClick
    ...
    state = !state
```

Answer (score 0):

Without animation

```
val visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Box() {
  if(visible){
     Composable1()
   }else{
     Composable2()
   }
}
```

With animation

```
val visible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Box() {
  AnimatedVisibility(visible = visible, 
    enter = fadeIn(tween()), //enter animation
    exit = fadeOut(tween(200)){ //exit animation
      Composable1()
  }
  AnimatedVisibility(visible = !visible, 
    enter = fadeIn(tween()), //enter animation
    exit = fadeOut(tween(200)){ //exit animation
      Composable2()
  }
}
```